# File name coming wrong when clicking open in save/Open Dialog

Tags: java, html, excel, jsp

I have a download button , on click of it I get a prompt asking for save/open .

if i click on save, file saves with proper name (as specified in header by content-disposition), 
but if i click on opens it open with a different name( the name of my action class).

i want it to open with same name as specified in header.

can someone help me with this, I am using IE8,Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the case when you're using IE. This odd browser ignores the `Content-Disposition` header altogether and will instead use the last path part of the request URI, which will be the form action URL as you specified in the `<form>`.

The only way to fix it is to let the form submit to an URL which includes the filename as last path part.

```html
<form action="fileservlet/filename.ext" method="post">
```

In the servlet which is for the above example mapped on an URL pattern of `/fileservlet/*`, you can if necessary grab that part as follows:

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1); // filename.ext
// ...
```